# Present $\alpha^{-1}\beta$ as a product of disjoint cycles, where $\alpha=(1\ 6)(3\ 2\ 8)$ and $\beta=(1\ 2\ 4)(3\ 5\ 7\ 6)(8\ 9\ 10)$.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $\alpha=(1\ 6)(3\ 2\ 8)$ and $\beta=(1\ 2\ 4)(3\ 5\ 7\ 6)(8\ 9\ 10)$

Present $\alpha^{-1}\beta$ as a product of disjoint cycles

$$\alpha^{-1} = (8\ 2\ 3)(1\ 6)$$

$$\alpha^{-1}\beta = (8\ 2\ 3)(1\ 6)(1\ 2\ 4)(3\ 5\ 7\ 6)(8\ 9\ 10)$$

In Cauchy notation
$$\alpha^{-1}\beta = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\
3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 1 & 9 & 10&  2
\end{pmatrix}$$

I'm struggling taking this back to cycle notation, is my inverse wrong?

Edit: So I have worked on it myself, and corrected my mistake with Cauchy notation. I work right to left for cycles and have reached the answer

$$\alpha^{-1}\beta = (1\ 3\ 5\ 7)(2\ 4\ 6\ 8\ 9\ 10)$$

Now I have to find the order of this, using lcm(4,6) I got $$|\alpha^{-1}\beta|=12$$

Comment: $1$ should map to $3$ so your Cauchy form is wrong.

Comment: Thank you I have edited it now I understand why my mistake happened.

Answer (score 2):

We wish to calculate the following in disjoint cycle notation
\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha^{-1} \beta = (8\ 2\ 3)(1\ 6)(1\ 2\ 4)(3\ 5\ 7\ 6)(8\ 9\ 10).
\end{eqnarray*}
Start with the element $1$ and reading left to right, $1$ is mapped to $6$ in the second cycle & the $6$ is mapped to $3$ in the fourth cycle, so $1$ maps to $3$. (So far $(1\ 3\ \cdots$).

Next $3$, $3$ is mapped to $8$ in the first cyle, which is mapped to $9$ in the last cycle (So far $(1\ 3\ 9\ \cdots)$).

Next $9$ is mapped to $10$ (So far $(1\ 3\ 9\ 10\  \cdots)$).

Continuing gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha^{-1} \beta = (1\ 3\ 9\ 10\ 8\ 4)(2\ 5\ 7\ 6).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Usually permutations are applied right to left, just like compositions of maps: $(\sigma\tau)(i) = \sigma(\tau(i))$. In your answer you seem to assume $(\sigma\tau)(i)=\tau(\sigma(i))$.

Comment: @Christoph There is a real confusion here, it seems half of us read our perms from left to right & then there are folks like you who (as you justify) read them from right to left. I hope it is clear that my perms run from left to right. Please forgive me if you find this backward!

Comment: Is there? I've only every seen permutations in $S_n$ being treated as bijections $[n]\to[n]$ with the usual composition of maps given by $(\sigma\circ\tau)(i) = \sigma(\tau(i))$. So indeed, your way of multiplying permutations seems backwards to me.

Comment: I have edited with what I got as the answer working right to left. I hope this is correct as it makes sense to me now!

Comment: Thank you both for your answers

Comment: @Christoph I've seen atleast one writer use the left to right format, so it is not entirely uncommon. I guess it works as long as it is mentioned in the answer.